# Queue with mod operation

Tags: c++, queue

I'm studying fundamental of data structure (Queue) , so far I understand the flow of Queue but I don't understand whenever queue is applying with Mod operator. There a several question which confusing my brain. How to answer this question (refer to picture)?

[image: Here the example of questions.]

Comment: Your question is also confusing my brain. I can't see the correlation between a queue and the questions you posted either. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @honk I don't know how to answer this question (refer to picture). Exp , what is the value for REAR after following this operation `REAR=(REAR+1)%N`whenever `REAR=4;N=5`. (N) is the maximum queue size.

Comment: Please read the answer by @Namfuak. He gives enough explanation so that you should be able so solve the equations by yourself.

Comment: @honk Indeed sir.. Sorry. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method for handling circular queues is to draw them out.  Since circles don't post very well with ASCII art, I'll use a linear array.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+  
  0   1   2   3   4  
                  ^  
                 Rear
```

The REAR is at index 4.

Let's perform the operation step by step.
First:  Add 1 to REAR.  This makes REAR point beyond the array:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+  
  0   1   2   3   4   5   
                      ^  
                      Rear
```

Applying the modulo operation, %, this will give us the remainder of `5 / 5` which is zero:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+  
  0   1   2   3   4     
  ^  
 Rear
```

Thus the modulo operation wraps around the array, like a circle.

The next question is for you to solve.  Remember draw the array or queue.  You can use circles (think of a pie sliced or a pizza sliced).

**Edit 1: Modulo details**
The modulo operation will give a value in the range 0..N, when N is the divisor.

Given N == 4, here are some results for modulo:

```
Index result
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       0  --> The remainder of 4 / 4 == 0.
5       1
6       2
7       3
8       0  -->  The remainder of 8 / 4 == 0.
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the explanation... I owe you so much. I got it now the flow of this queue..

Answer (score 2):

Modulus returns the remainder of the two operands.  For example, `4%2=0` since `4/2=2` with no remainder, while `4%3=1` since `4/3=1` with remainder 1.  Since you can never have a remainder higher than the right operand, you have an effective "range" of answers for any modulus of `0` to `(n-1)`.  With that in mind, just plug in the numbers for the variables (`(4+1)%5=?` and `(1+1)%4=?`).  Usually to find the remainder you would use long division, but one useful thing to remember is that any number divided by itself has a remainder of 0, and any number divided by a larger number will have a remainder equal to itself.

Comment: Ohhhh.. I remember now, thanks for the explanation sir. Glad you came here to help. I understand now the question now.. Sorry. ^^